# How to access current location and set that as initial location?

Tags: flutter, async-await, location, openstreetmap

I have a Flutter app which requires location services. I have already implemented getting a users current location, permissions, etc...

My app has to position a marker on a map when first open based on the **current location** of the user. *(This is what I need help with)*

The user can later touch the map at any other point to place the marker at that point. *(This I have already done)*

I have successfully created a function which can retrieve the current location of a user like this, *(Do note that that function is async)*

```dart
Future<LatLng> get currentLocation async {
  Position pos = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  );
  return LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude);
}
```

I currently have `LatLng markerPoint = LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);` as my **initial marker point** inside of my **HomePage** like this,

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // Initial marker location
  LatLng markerPoint = LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946);
  ...
```

But I want the **current location** returned by my function to replace the values given here. I am unable to do something like `LatLng markerPoint = await _locationService.currentLocation;` because I cannot make that part of the class **async**.

So, that's basically my problem. I want to initialise my variable through an asynchronous function, but I haven't found a way to do that since the area I am in, does not allow for async functions.

Help will be appreciated.

**PS:**

My remaining build function which sets the marker point whenever touched is over here for your reference.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            onTap: (tapPosition, point) async {
              setState(() {
                markerPoint = point;
              });
            },
            //
            center: markerPoint,
            zoom: 10.0,
            // this is required to disable rotation of the map
            // the map will behave wierd when you rotate it if it's deleted
            // the map will not scroll properly and not place markers at the exact locations.
            // if the below line in removed
            interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.all & ~InteractiveFlag.rotate,
          ),
          nonRotatedChildren: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              subdomains: const ['a', 'b', 'c'],
            ),
            MarkerLayer(
              markers: [
                Marker(
                  width: 100.0,
                  height: 100.0,
                  point: markerPoint,
                  builder: (ctx) => const Icon(
                    Icons.location_on,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Card(
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
                      hintText: "Search for a location",
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    ),
                    onTap: () async {
                      // This is here for debugging only, kindly ignore
                      await requestPermission();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope you are calling the get current location api in the initState() method

eg :

```
@override
void initState() {

    super.initState();
    fetchCurrentLocation();
   
  }

void fetchCurrentLocation() async{
 //calling the api
    var currentLocation = await _locationService.currentLocation; 

    //setState will update the values in real time
    setState(() {

      markerPoint = currentLocation

    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but there is a problem. I can see that the state is first created, but then the marker point changes. The speed at which this happens is very small to the eye, but what happens is that the map remains centred to the previous initial default point and not the current location as it should.

Comment: I was able to solve that issue also using a MapController of the FlutterMap. Thanks for helping me out. Saved a lot of my time.

Comment: glad this helped you